# Created a SQL agent Job to run a package which uses FTP connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis, runtime-error, script-task, sql-agent

I created a SQL agent Job to run a package which uses FTP connection. The package contains a script task to get run time variable values and create a new output file.  package runs locally successfully, When I run through job it throws below error.

> CORP\U4PWMCA1. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.6560.0 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  3:06:26 PM  Error: 2019-04-25 15:06:27.79     Code: 0x00000008     Source: SCR_Set_Global_Variables      Description: The script returned a failure result.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  3:06:26 PM  Finished: 3:06:27 PM  Elapsed:  1.078 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Can you please suggest what is the issue?

Comment: Please provide the script task code